# How can I config sublime text excute javascript with Mozilla Rhino

Tags: text-editors, javascript, firefox, sublime-text-2

I want to excute javascript file without a browser. I found Mozila Rhino, but I wonder that how can I config sublime text or another text editor run my .js file directly (i.e without run command line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux solution:

Create a bash file: `/usr/sbin/rhino`

```
#!/bin/sh
java -cp /opt/rhino1_7R3/js.jar:. org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main "$@"
```

Note: `/opt/rhino1_7R3` is where I installed my rhino — you can extract it where you please.

On Sublime, go to *Tools » Build System » New Build System*. Paste the following and save the file.

```
{
    "cmd": ["rhino", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.javascript"
}
```